# how to find the following limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

**Problem**: Find the following limit $${\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin\frac{\pi}{n^{2}}+\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\sin\frac{2\pi}{n^{2}}+\ldots+\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\sin\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{n^{2}}\pi\right]}$$.

**Attempt:**
Observe that 
\begin{align*}
 & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin\frac{\pi}{n^{2}}+\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\sin\frac{2\pi}{n^{2}}+\ldots+\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\sin\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{n^{2}}\pi\right]\\
= & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{n^{2}}+O\left(\frac{\pi^{3}}{n^{6}}\right)\right)+\ldots+\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\left(\left(\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}\right)\pi+O\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)^{3}\pi^{3}}{n^{6}}\right)\right)\right]\\
= & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{k\pi}{n^{2}}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)O\left(\frac{k^{3}\pi^{3}}{n^{6}}\right)\right)\right]\\
= & \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{k\pi}{n^{2}}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)\right]\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n^{3}} & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^{4}}\right)\leq\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)=0.
\end{align*}
Hence 
\begin{align*}
\left(1\right) & =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\frac{k\pi}{n^{2}}\right]=\pi\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{2}\right)\frac{1}{n}\right]\\
 & =\pi\int_{0}^{1}x+x^{2}dx=\frac{5\pi}{6}.
\end{align*}

**Question** I don't know if I did it correctly.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: I am not sure that I see the question. Could you clarify ?

Comment: Is this a proof verification?

Comment: You have the answer correct. It is $\frac{5\pi}{6}$$  Hmm this link doesn't paste correctly - use copy and paste to get it all: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BSum%5B(1+%2B+i%2Fn)+Sin%5Bi*Pi%2Fn%5E2%5D,+%7Bi,+1,+n+-+1%7D%5D,+n+-%3E+Infinity%5D

Comment: What is even funny is that, for finite values of $n$, the summation has a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did this perfectly except for one (inconsequential) mistake. In "note that", you should have

$$ \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \left( 1 + \dfrac{k}{n} \right) \dfrac{1}{n^3} & = \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{n^4} \\
& < \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \mathbf{ \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n}{n^4} } \\
& = \dfrac{1}{n^2} + \dfrac{1}{n^2}
\end{align*} $$

which still tends to 0.

If you'd like some empirical confidence boosting,

[image: Mathematica produces this convergence on a numerical level very clearly.]
<sub>(source: [pages.iu.edu](http://pages.iu.edu/~ttager/convergence.jpg))</sub>